# Sorting with item and Drag and drop for delete

Tags: jquery-ui

I want **gp_item** should be sortable and when drag and drop under **gp_delete** area **gp_item** should get deleted.

When I did, it either working sorting or deleting. Both not working together.

```
<div id='container_gp'>
<div id='1' class='gp_item'> Graph 1</div>
<div id='2' class='gp_item'> Graph 2</div>
<div id='3' class='gp_item'> Graph 3</div>
</div>

<div id='gp_delete'>Drop to delete here </div>
```

I have written like that.

```
$('.gp_item').draggable({   
            revert: true,
            proxy:'clone'

        });

$("#gp_delete").droppable({
            activeClass: "active",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if(confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete"))
                {
                    //delete code
                    ui.draggable.remove();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ckWKE/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit your code and now works, the trick is to set the `draggable` and `sortable` features on the container not on single elements:

```
$('#container_gp').sortable({revert: 100}).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    proxy: 'clone'
}).disableSelection()

$("#gp_delete").droppable({
    activeClass: "active",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    accept: '#container_gp div',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete")) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckWKE/2/